# Specifying additional subclassed bounds of a TypeVar in Python typing

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, structural-typing

When using type hints combined with mypy, I want to define a generic class that allows access to an attribute that is only available for some of the generic classes. I am wondering how to define this in Python type hints.

For instance, let's have the following example:

```python
class SomeObject:
    pass
class SomeObjectWithAttr:
    def __init__(self, attr):
        self.attr = attr

class AppendListWithAttrs:
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = []
        self._attrs = []
    def append(self, obj, record_attr=False):
        self._list.append(obj)
        if record_attr:
            self._attrs.append(obj.attr)

l = AppendListWithAttrs()
l.append(SomeObject())
l.append(SomeObjectWithAttr())
l.append(SomeObjectWithAttr(), record_attr=True)
```

I have attempted annotating this, but mypy can't seem to get happy. This is my best attempt:

```python
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Protocol, overload, Literal, Union

T = TypeVar("T")

class HasAttr(Protocol):
    attr: str

class AppendListWithAttrs(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self._list: list[T] = []
        self._attrs: list[str] = []

    @overload
    def append(self: 'AppendListWithAttrs[HasAttr]', obj: HasAttr, record_attr: Literal[True]): ...
    @overload
    def append(self, obj: T, record_attr: Literal[False]): ...

    def append(self, obj: T, record_attr: bool = False):
        self._list.append(obj)
        if record_attr:
            self._attrs.append(obj.attr)
```

This is also not quite correct, but I'm effectively looking for a way to tell mypy that `T` can be anything, but if it is bounded by `HasAttr`, it may access this `attr`. Perhaps something like subclassing `T` with `HasAttr`, but maybe I'm looking at this wrong.

How would you annotate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? It [passes MyPy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes&gist=ac595111fe9de5369525c6d66abc77a9).

```
from typing import overload, Literal, Union, Any, Protocol, Generic, TypeVar


class GenericObjectProto(Protocol):
    pass


class ObjectWithAttrProto(GenericObjectProto, Protocol):
    attr: str
        
    
T = TypeVar('T', bound=GenericObjectProto)


class AppendListWithAttrs(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._list: list[T] = []
        self._attrs: list[str] = []
        
    @overload
    def append(self, obj: GenericObjectProto, record_attr: Literal[False] = False) -> None: ...
    
    @overload
    def append(self, obj: ObjectWithAttrProto, record_attr: Literal[True] = ...) -> None: ...
        
    def append(self, obj,  record_attr: bool = False) -> None:
        self._list.append(obj)
        if record_attr:
            self._attrs.append(obj.attr)
            

class SomeObject:
    pass


class SomeObjectWithAttr:
    def __init__(self, attr: str) -> None:
        self.attr = attr


mylist = AppendListWithAttrs[SomeObject]()
mylist.append(SomeObject())
mylist.append(SomeObjectWithAttr('hello'))
mylist.append(SomeObjectWithAttr('hello'), record_attr=True)
reveal_type(mylist._list) # Revealed type is "builtins.list[__main__.SomeObject*]"
```

**How it works**

We can get some special type-hinting magic by having our `ObjectWithAttr` protocol inherit from our `GenericObject` protocol. By doing this, we have defined `ObjectWithAttr` as a *structural* subtype of `GenericObject`. This means that MyPy does not complain when we append an instance of `SomeObjectWithAttr` to a list of `SomeObject` instances. Because of the "structural inheritance" scheme we've defined, MyPy understands `SomeObjectWithAttr` to be fully compatible with a list of `SomeObject` instances, even though there is no *actual* inheritance going on.

**Caveats**

This passes MyPy, but only if you don't use it with the `--strict` setting, since I didn't annotate `obj` in the concrete implementation of `.append`. MyPy appears to be able to infer the types perfectly with the existing annotations, but it will nonetheless complain that you've left out an annotation if you run the above code as-is on the `--strict` setting. Even with the overloads, it doesn't like you annotating `obj` with `T` or a `Union` type (which seems a little buggy to me), so if you're running MyPy on `--strict`, you can either annotate `obj` in the concrete implementation with `Any`, or put a `# type: ignore[no-untyped-def]` at the end of the line.